# Azure APIM Inbound Policy - validate-content - unable to dynamically set schema-id

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I am trying to use validate-content policy to validate the json payload of my requests in Azure APIM. My API request payloads will have a property called schemaName. For example the request payload will be like this:
{
"schemaId":"app1-schema1",
"propertyAbc": 123
}
In APIM > Schemas, I have saved multiple json schemas with names like "app1-schema1", "app1-schema2", etc.
To do the validation in API, I have include this inbound snippet:

```
    <policies>
     <inbound>      
        <set-variable name="Schema" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true)["schemaId"].Value<string>())" />
        <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validateError">
            <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="@(context.Variables["Schema"])" />
        </validate-content>
        <base />
     </inbound>
     <backend>
        <base />
     </backend>
     <outbound>
        <base />
     </outbound>
     <on-error>
        <base />
     </on-error>
 </policies>
```

I am unable to save this policy configuration from Azure Portal. I get the following error:
*One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Error in element 'validate-content' on line 16, column 10: The schema @(context.Variables["Schema"]) does not exist.*
If I hardcode the value of schema-id to be "app1-schema1", then i am able to save the policy configuration.
Does this mean one cannot dynamically set the name of the schema-id property?

Answer (score 0):

> I get the following error: *One or more fields contain incorrect values: Error in element 'validate-content' on line 16, column 10: The schema @(context.Variables["Schema"]) does not exist.* If I hardcode the value of schema-id to be "app1-schema1", then i am able to save the policy configuration. Does this mean one cannot dynamically set the name of the schema-id property?

Yes, it looks like **`schema-id`** in `validate-content` policy accepts static values and throwing error for expressions like **'@{}' and '@()'**.

You can provide the value of **schema-id** parameter explicitly or can skip it too, as its an optional parameter.

If you want to pass it dynamically, you can set the schema-id values in ***Named Values*** and use it as given below-

[image]

```xml
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validateError">
    <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="{{schemaName}}" />
</validate-content>
```

There is an alternative way to add the schema definition in API level, if you don't want to hardcode the value of **schema-id**.

Click on **definitions**

[image]

Enter the definition name and add a sample Json to generate the payload and then click on *Create definition*.

[image]

Once the definition is created, you can use it in your operation directly as shown below.

[image]

Select the definition from the dropdown.

[image]

Once the schema is added, no need to pass the schema-id in the policy.

```xml
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validateError">
    <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
</validate-content>
```

By using this policy, I am able to get expected response.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ikhtesam-Afrin. The alternative option you have mentioned still restricts me to have only one Schema, it is just that it is now defined within the API definition instead of a separate Schema json saved in APIM>Schema. My idea was to make the schema-id dynamic so that I can verify different payloads coming in via the same api by just referring to the schema id that is part of the payload itself.

Comment: @AzureDev Yes I have understood your requirement but it looks like a limitation in the validate-content policy. You can try using the named values method to pass the schema I'd there